# I am unable to identify search form which is displayed and is visible

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am unable to identify search form which is displayed and is visible. The type is hidden.

```
<form id="searchForm" name="searchForm" method="post" action="/mpstage/pages/content/shop?jfwid=5bcbhia8v" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
   <input name="searchForm_SUBMIT" value="1" type="hidden"/>
```

Comment: html code is missing.

Comment: what is your question? the control you want has a name, why not use it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.name("searchForm_SUBMIT"));  
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;  
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

First we store the hidden element as an object. Then use js executer to click on the element